# Open scala REPL with project definitions

Tags: scala, sbt

I tried to run `sbt console` on [this repo](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files) but I can't access project class/objects.

What's missing me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`project core` first. Then open `console`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. What does the `project core` task do?

Comment: `aggregate` is not `dependsOn` in sbt, it seems.

Comment: You must change to the subproject named `core`. The `root` aggregates the subprojects but does not `dependsOn` them. You can `project akka` and still see `core` classes, for instance.